# Preventing iFrame showing on initial page load in IE & Android

Tags: css, iframe

I have a page that when a link is clicked an iFrame appears in a Modal showing the .pdf file. I found an interesting article that explained how to do this without any JavaScript. The code is:
HTML

```
<span id="initials" data-tooltip="Click to see my Resume"><a href="#openModal">JJ</a></span>

<div id="openModal" class="modal">
      <div> <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
         <h2>My Resume</h2>
         <iframe src="doc/resume.pdf"> </iframe>
      </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    **opacity: 0;**
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.modal:target {
    **opacity:1;**
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

From what I understood from article when the link is clicked the target pseudo-class is triggered and the iFrame pops up in modal with nice transition from opacity change. And it works like a charm in FF/Chrome. However in IE or my Android Chrome browser the iFrame is loading on initial page request. I looked here and saw this solution

```
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
  window.frames[0].document.execCommand('Stop');
} else {
  window.frames[0].stop();
}
```

but it prevents iFrame from loading altogether. I've googled and found no solution that pertains to this. Would appreciate if anyone has any ideas on how to get this to work in IE and Android. Here's [Link](http://akillian.x10host.com/my_portfolio/) Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is interested here is a solution I came up with.

```
<div id="openModal" class="modal">
      <div> <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
         <h2>My Resume</h2>
         <iframe id="iframeDisplay" src=""> </iframe>
      </div>
  </div>

 <!-- ================================================================================
   This Javascript is required for IE and Android browsers. It seems that they do not
   respect the opacity property on load so need a hack to make it work...        =====
  ================================================================================ -->


<script>
    if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 800px)").matches) {
        /* the viewport is no more then 800 pixels wide
            so no modal ==============================*/
        var anchorElement = document.querySelector('.classInitials');
        anchorElement.setAttribute("href", "doc/resume.pdf");
        // Create and set a target attribute
        anchorElement.createAttribute("target");
        anchorElement.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    }
    else {
        /* the viewport is greater than 800 pixels wide
            and make .pdf popup in a modal ============*/
        var iframeElement = document.querySelector('#iframeDisplay');
        document.getElementById("initials").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            // Make iFrame appear on click
            iframeElement = document.querySelector('#iframeDisplay');
            iframeElement.setAttribute("src", "doc/resume.pdf");
            document.getElementById("iframeDisplay").style.display = "block";
        }, false);
        /*getElementsByClassName actually returns an HTMLCollection, even though you have only one element with that classname in DOM, so you have to retrieve it with index 0. Alternatively, since we only have one element with the classname, you can safely use querySelector, which will return the first match element.*/
        var element = document.querySelector('.close');
        element.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            // Change iframe back to invisible and src to ""
            iframeElement.setAttribute("src", "");
            document.getElementById("iframeDisplay").style.display = "none";
        }, false);
    }
```

I start with src="" so mobile browsers and IE wont load iframe. Then I use a media query to see if its a mobile device and then use JS to manipulate the DOM to not load pdf as iframe instead just load in separate tab.